# How to convert a vector<pair<int,int> > to multimap<int,int> efficiently?

Tags: c++, data-structures

`How to convert a multimap<int,int> to vector<pair<int,int> > efficiently`

EDIT:
Sorry for the trouble I was actually looking for converting vector to map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value type of a `multimap<int,int>` is `pair<int,int>` - exactly what you would like your vector to hold. So, you can use the constructor to initialize the vector from the multimap:

```
std::vector< std::pair<int,int> > v( mmap.begin(), mmap.end() );
```

Or, if you have an existing vector where you want to copy the elements:

```
v.resize( mmap.size() );
std::copy( mmap.begin(), mmap.end(), v.begin() );
```

You can also use the `std::back_inserter`, but that would be slower in general due to vector reallocations:

```
std::copy( mmap.begin(), mmap.end(), std::back_inserter(v) );
```

**EDIT**
To answer your other question - you can convert a vector to a multimap in a similar way. The multimap also has a constructor which accepts an iterator range:

```
std::multimap<int,int> mmap(v.begin(), v.end());
```

This, of course, assumes that `v` is `std::vector< std::pair<int,int> >`.

Comment: The value type of associative containers in C++ has a constant key. That is: std::multimap<Key,Value>::value_type is std::pair< const Key, Value>. The reason is that if the Key was not constant, it could be changed through non-const iterators breaking the container invariants (the element would be in a wrong position after the key update)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the naive approach is also the most efficient one: iterate over the multimap, and add each element to the vector. As an optimization, you should `v.reserve(m.size)` before you start.

The elements are typically stored in a tree in the multimap, in objects spread over the heap. For the vector, they must be in contiguous memory: this requires that you really have to copy them together.

Comment: No need: vector::assign(Iter begin, Iter end) is a single operation that takes care of both the memory allcoation and the loop.